# Allow participants to view transactions they submitted

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've set up a business network using hyperledger composer. I am trying to set permissions such that participants are allowed to view only the transactions they have submitted.

Attempting to access the transactions (called TradeInstrument) either via a GET request to the composer REST API or using client API works when called as admin. This is understandable as I have allowed admin access to all resources. However, when I make the request as a participant, an empty array is returned. What is the right way to set permissions for what I am trying to achieve?

Here are my model and permissions files:

model.cto

```
namespace org.example.cashbalance

participant Portfolio identified by portfolioNumber {
  o String portfolioNumber
  o String portfolioName
}

transaction TradeInstrument {
  --> Portfolio participant
  o Double settlementAmountBase 
}
```

permissions.acl

```
rule ParticipantCanSeeOwnTransactions {
    description: "Allow participants to view transactions they have submitted"
    participant(t): "org.example.cashbalance.Portfolio"
    operation: ALL
    resource(v): "org.example.cashbalance.TradeInstrument"
    condition: (v.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() == t.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "ANY"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're talking about historical transactions (already submitted), so you need to restrict that registry eg.

```
rule PortfolioParticipantSeesOwnHistoryOnly {
  description: "See history of their own transactions only"
  participant(t): "org.example.cashbalance.Portfolio"
  operation: READ
  resource(v): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  condition: (v.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() != t.getIdentifier())
  action: DENY
}
```

I don't think the rule below will do anything (participantInvoking is an attribute of 'HistorianRecord' )

```
rule ParticipantCanSeeOwnTransactions {
    description: "Allow participants to view transactions they have submitted"
    participant(t): "org.example.cashbalance.Portfolio"
    operation: ALL
    resource(v): "org.example.cashbalance.TradeInstrument"
    condition: (v.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() == t.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```